# Como filtrar Coluna no JTable com dados do tipo Calendar

Tags: java, jtable, calendar, rowfilter

Estou tentando filtrar datas usando o *TableRowFilter*, mas não esta funcionando corretamente mesmo selecionando no filtro a coluna exata e por exemplo digitando `24/11/2017` o filtro apos digitar a primeira barra todos os dados somem no *JTable*.

Modelo da Tabela

```
import br.com.blogspot.denisbenjamim.decoretor.tabelas.EntradaContainersArmazenados_DecoretorTabela;
import br.com.blogspot.denisbenjamim.pojo.TransportadoraContainer;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class EntradaContainersArmazenados_ModelTable extends Abstract_ModeloTabelas<TransportadoraContainer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6143338956876947248L;

    public EntradaContainersArmazenados_ModelTable(EntradaContainersArmazenados_DecoretorTabela aThis, String... colunas) {
        super(aThis, colunas);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        try {
            TransportadoraContainer objeto = this.linhas.get(rowIndex);
            objeto.setTipoDocumento(TransportadoraContainer.Tipo.ENTRADA);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return objeto.getOS();
                case 1:
                    return objeto.getContainer();
                case 2:
                    return objeto.isCobrado();
                case 3:
                    return objeto.getDataPago();
                case 4:                   
                    if(objeto.getValorPago() != null)
                      return DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(objeto.getValorPago() );
                    return null;
                case 5:
                    return objeto.getTipoPagamento();
                case 6:
                    return objeto.getTipo();
                case 7:
                    return objeto.getDataEntrada();                
                case 8:
                    return objeto.getDataSaida();
                case 9:
                    return objeto.getReservaEntrada();
                case 10:
                    return objeto.getTransportadora();
                case 11:
                    return objeto.getCNH_ENTRADA();
                case 12:
                    return objeto.getPlcCavEntrada();
                case 13:
                    return objeto.getPlcBugEntrada();
                case 14:
                    return objeto.getDs_documento();
                 case 15:
                    return objeto.isCancelado();
                case 16:
                    return objeto.getDataCancelado();
                case 17:
                    return objeto.getUsuarioQCancelou();
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException boundsException) {
            boundsException.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(TransportadoraContainer aValue, int rowIndex) {
        TransportadoraContainer n1 = this.linhas.get(rowIndex);
        TransportadoraContainer n2 = aValue;

        n1.setArmazenamento(n2.getArmazenamento());
        n1.setCNH_ENTRADA(n2.getCNH_ENTRADA());
        n1.setCNH_SAIDA(n2.getCNH_SAIDA());
        n1.setCobrado(n2.isCobrado());
        n1.setContainer(n2.getContainer());
        n1.setDataEntrada(n2.getDataEntrada());
        n1.setDataPago(n2.getDataPago());
        n1.setDataSaida(n2.getDataSaida());
        n1.setDs_documento(n2.getDs_documento());
        n1.setTcls(n2.getTcls());
        n1.setNm_credor(n2.getNm_credor());
        n1.setOS(n2.getOS());
        n1.setOpv(n2.getOpv());
        n1.setExportador(n2.getExportador());
        n1.setReservaEntrada(n2.getReservaEntrada());
        n1.setReservaSaida(n2.getReservaSaida());
        n1.setTerminalRetirada(n2.getTerminalRetirada());
        n1.setTipo(n2.getTipo());
        n1.setTipoPagamento(n2.getTipoPagamento());
        n1.setTransportadora(n2.getTransportadora());
        n1.setValorPago(n2.getValorPago());
        n1.setCancelado(n2.isCancelado());
        n1.setPlcBugEntrada(n2.getPlcBugEntrada());
        n1.setPlcCavEntrada(n2.getPlcCavEntrada());
        n1.setPlcBugSaida(n2.getPlcBugSaida());
        n1.setPlcCavSaida(n2.getPlcCavSaida());
        n1.setUsuarioQCancelou(n2.getUsuarioQCancelou());
        n1.setDataCancelado(n2.getDataCancelado());

        for (int i = 0; i < getColumnCount(); i++) {
            fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 3:           
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 16:
                return Calendar.class;
            case 2:
            case 15:
                return Boolean.class;
            default:
                return Object.class;
        }

    }

}
```

Evento responsável:

```
 case "pesquisa":
                try {
                    if ((view.getjTF_pesquisaRegistros().getText().isEmpty()) || (8 == evt.getKeyCode())) {
                        if (view.getjCB_naoExibirDaCasa().isSelected()) {
                            getController().naoExibirRegistrosDaCasa();
                        } else {
                            getController().getSorterRegistros().setRowFilter(null);
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            int coluna = view.getJcb_prmPesquisa().getSelectedIndex();
                            if (coluna < 0) {
                                Utils.painelDeMensagens("Seleciona uma Coluna", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                view.getJcb_prmPesquisa().requestFocus();
                                return;
                            }
                            RowFilter<JTableUtils, Object> rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + view.getjTF_pesquisaRegistros().getText(), coluna);
                            getController().getSorterRegistros().setRowFilter(rf);
                        } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não existe.", "Erro", 0);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (HeadlessException exception) {
                    controller.getLOG().error("Problema com a Pesquisa", exception);
                    Utils.painelDeMensagens("Problema com a Pesquisa", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
```

Comment: Insira o código para facilitar a resolução do problema.

Comment: Sua dúvida já foi respondida numa pergunta feita por mim há algum tempo. Se quiser algo mais específico, forneça um [mcve]

Comment: Exemplo fornecido com codigo principal o qual funciona perfeitamente desde que a classe nao seja um Calendar. Pergunto pois deve haver uma forma de especificar para o Filter o como ele deve ler o dado no caso do calendar ele em forma de string tem muita informação

Comment: Não seria tipo Date? Se for, como eu já disse, já tem uma ótima resposta.

Comment: Não eu uso tipo calendar mesmo, Utilizo no render e no editor um JDateChooser. Bom Pelo visto vou ter de continuar procurando Obrigado Articuno e por favor seja menos severo comigo

Comment: Não tem ninguém sendo severo aqui. Você veio com uma dúvida, eu apontei pra uma ótima solução na resposta do Victor pra um problema idêntico que tive. Agora se você não quis nem sequer testar a solução lá, aí eu não tenho culpa alguma.

Comment: Eu vi a sua solução é bem viavel, eu havia lido em algum lugar sobre o RowSorter solicitar o toString  como voce mesmo debugou e notou isso a aquela classe foi muito bem elaborada, Parabens.

Comment: A reabertura desta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6616/reabertura-de-pergunta-duplicata-mesmo-ela-continuando-sendo-duplicata

Comment: Por que foi reaberta?

Comment: @DenisBenjamim Acredito que foi reaberta por engano ou por descuido, fechei como duplicata novamente. A julgar pelo seu comentário acima, me parece que você concorda que é duplicata, mas se não concordar, sinta-se livre para comentar.

Comment: Sim concordo apesar de estar usando Calendar e não um Date como no caso do Articuno. Eu adaptei a versão no post dele para minha necessidade dentro Render/Editor personalizado que eu ja utilizava.

Comment: Calendar não é um tipo adequado para o que está fazendo. Você precisa representar um ponto no tempo, é para isso que existem as classes de datas. No caso deste componente, existe um método que recupera um tipo Date, que é o [`getDate()`](http://www.se.rit.edu/~sal/uitutorials/uitot/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#getDate()).

Comment: É questionavel dizer que um Calendar é ou não é adequado para o que estou fazendo, eu acho mais simples de trabalhar em muitas operações e funciona perfeitamente a minha necessidade. Sou conhecedor do getDate() do componente e do getTime() da classe Calendar. Quando fiz uso do exemplo que passou eu fiz as devidas adaptações coloquei a funcionalidade dentro da classe que faz o render e o editor. So fiquei curioso sobre um detalhe, por que implementar Comparable ?

Comment: @DenisBenjamim Segundo o javadoc do [`TableRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html): "*3. If the column class implements `Comparable`, use a `Comparator` that invokes the `compareTo` method.*" Ou seja, em colunas que implementam `Comparable`, um `Comparator` que invoca o método `compareTo` será usado. Assim sendo, o `implements Comparable` é necessário para que o `TableRowSorter` saiba como fazer a (re)ordenação dos dados usando a data como critério de ordenação.

Comment: Sim é verdade ao clicar nas colunas para ordenar o metodo é chamado. Mas estou notando um desempenho horrivel na hora de filtrar as colunas do tipo data mesmo com a custom class. Acho que vou abrir uma pergunta sobre esse desempenho horrivel

Comment: @DenisBenjamim É melhor criar uma pergunta diferente mesmo.